# Packaging External Libraries in APK

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, apk

I have some External Libraries included in my Xamarin Android Project using Visual Studio , like NewtonSoft , Xamarin.TextToSpeech  and more .
Problem is when I'm Building project as "Release" in VS , it is not including these external lib in the package , thus App Crash.

Working fine when I deploy same project as "debug" mode .

[image: Build Page]

What can be done to include these external lib in the APK .
 is there any packaging settings in VS that can be manipulated ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual crash/exception/stacktrace?

Comment: @SushiHangover package is created with no problem , there was no error , when I installed app using Packaged "Released" APK , app was crashing when using json dependencies , thus I think those lib are not packages in APK.

Comment: You can unzip the `.apk` to confirm that the assemblies are there, but I would assume that is not your problem. You should monitor logcat and get the error that is being produced.

Comment: @AnkitPassi can you post the Android Build option screen what you have set in the Setting menu.

Comment: @Ironman just updated question!

Comment: The linker is probably being too aggressive here and linking out methods in these libraries that are used but not being detected. Try switching the link mode to "None" in a Release app and see if it still fails. Or perhaps I'm not sure what you mean by "External Libraries". Can you please add to your question how you are adding these items to your project and `.apk`?

Comment: @JonDouglas setting it to "None" doesn't helped at all , it is not running as it should  ,I am using Newtonsoft json package , xamarin text to speech and twilio apis for my application . I am referring these as "external packages"

Comment: Can you please post an `adb logcat` to the point of failure in your original post then?